# What's the big deal with tail-call optimization and why does Python need it?

Tags: python, tail-recursion, tail-call-optimization

Apparently, there's been a big brouhaha over whether or not Python needs tail-call optimization (TCO).  This came to a head when someone [shipped Guido a copy of SICP](http://drj11.wordpress.com/2009/04/30/python-tail-call-optimisation/), because he didn't "get it."  I'm in the same boat as [Guido](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guido_van_Rossum).  I understand the concept of tail-call optimization.  I just can't think of any reason why Python really *needs* it.

To make this easier for me to understand, what would be a snippet of code that would be greatly simplified using TCO?

Comment: The discussion wasn't so much about Python *needing* TCO, but about Guido rejecting it for the wrong reasons.

Comment: I am glad nobody closed this question as primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Personally, I put great value on tail call optimization; but mainly because it makes recursion as efficient as iteration (or makes iteration a subset of recursion). In minimalistic languages you get huge expressive power without sacrificing performance.

In a 'practical' language (like Python), OTOH, you usually have a lot of other constructions for almost every situation imaginable, so it's less critical. It is always a good thing to have, to allow for unforeseen situations, of course.

Comment: That's about what I suspected, but I figured there must be a bigger reason for it.  I suppose I was wrong.

Comment: but remember that those 'minimalistic languages' that i mention (Lua and Scheme, for example) are usually both nicer and much faster than Python.  in part because having reliable tail call optimization frees your mind and makes programs clearer.  unfortunately, i don't know any one as practical as Python.

Answer (score 6):

If you intensely want to use recursion for things that might alternatively be expressed as loops, then "tail call optimization" is really a must. However, Guido, Python's Benevolent Dictator For Life (BDFL), strongly believes in loops being expressed as loops -- so he's not going to special-case tail calls (sacrificing stack-trace dumps and debugging regularity).

Answer (score 5):

[Tail-call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call_optimization) makes it easier to write recursive functions without worrying about a stack overflow:

```
def fac(n, result=1):
        if n > 1:
                return fac(n - 1, n * result)
        return result
```

Without tail-call optimization, calling this with a big number could overflow the stack.

Comment: Standard academic example. Any example with real world usage?

Comment: in fact, this isn't tail recursive.  the multiplication is in the tail, not the recursion.

Comment: def fac(n): return reduce(operator.mul, range(1, n+1))

Comment: @Javier, the multiplication is in the tail, and there is no "pending" operation to perform, once the recursive call returns. Hence, that makes it tail recursive. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Amit: He was correct originally, I changed the example. But even with the original, a smart compiler could have optimized it.

Comment: @Zifre: right, the new form is so widely recognized as efficient, that Scheme purists refer to this as 'iteration, not recursion', since the TCO produces the same code as a while(){...} loop

Comment: @ebo: "Standard academic example. Any example with real world usage?" Asynchronous state machines, commonly seen in F# server code.

Answer (score 0):

Guido recognized in a follow up [post](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com.es/2009/04/final-words-on-tail-calls.html) that TCO allowed a cleaner the implementation of state machine as a collection of functions recursively calling each other. However in the same post he proposes an alternative equally cleaner solution without TCO.

Comment: The way to achieve TCO in the post looks (IMO) roundabout, and it also adds a constant factor to your program: instead of your program going call-call-call, it would go call-return-call-return-call-return. I guess that’s the main criticism: people would like to express state-machine-like behaviour directly. But currently you’d blow the stack like that, so you’d need to revert to the “loop and return a tuple” method.